# coloring text with Java in Windows

Tags: java, colors, console, cmd

I knew that in Linux Console we can write something like this

```
System.out.println("\033[31mhello");
```

so that the result will be "hello" (without quotes) and the color will be red...

is there any way to do this on windows? or is there any software that can handle the exactly same thing on windows?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need a .DLL file to get decent console output on windows. Try one of the following:

- [Jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/)
- [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to format the Windows console command output...the caveat is that you need to load the ANSI.SYS driver...You can refer to the following links:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: I don't get why I have been downvoted...but to make it happens under Windows in the same way as Linux console (where you can send escape characters), we need to redirect the I/O stream to STDIN/STDOUT rather than System.out.print overloaded methods. Anyway, I haven't tried this.