# Use of System.err.println() in Java

Tags: java

On standard console all things are printed in white whether we have written it in `System.out` or `System.err`. In IDE(for me Eclipse) we can see different color output on console for both. i.e. black for `System.out` and red for `System.err`.

Is `System.err` is only provided for use in IDEs? Cause on cmd we can not distinguish `System.out` and `System.err`. Both are printed in same color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two different output streams that are available in most of OS's. You don't have them color coded due to settings of your terminal/command line environment. On the other hand your IDE provides different visualization for different streams.

If you wanted to color them, consider using ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: @Oleg: It would be helpful to tell Harry how this might be possible.

Comment: @Dave, so you think that answering original question is not enough in this case and it deserves minus from you?

Comment: @Oleg: I feel that all answers that do not discuss the possibility of colouring the two different streams should get a -1. Just because an answer is technically correct does not mean it is a useful answer in practise.

Comment: @Dave, unless question was actually "Is System.err is only provided for use in IDEs?" and not "How to color code the output", don't you agree?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis - your downvote is based on an incorrect reading of the question.  The OP doesn't want to know how to change the colour of the text.  He wants to know if there is a way to get the console to do this ... without tinkering with his application.

Comment: @Oleg & Stephen: In that case, should the answer not discuss piping the different streams through an ANSI escape sequence that colours the text? (-1 removed.)

Comment: @Dave - no.  The OP wants the console to "just do it".  Like Eclipse does.  And there's no technical reason that the console (or shell) can't.  Indeed, in JNode we implemented the console to do just this; i.e. display output to the 'stderr' and 'stdout' streams in different colors.

Answer (score 3):

`System.out` goes to the standard output stream (stdout) and `System.err` goes to the standard error stream (stderr). See [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for details and how you can control where they go. Eclipse just conveniently colour codes them for you so you can distinguish them in one view.

Comment: @Dave: I only see one sentence with a question from the OP: "Is System.err only provided for use in IDEs?" Kudos though for going further and explaining how one could go about getting color on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

From [system-in-out-error](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html):

> System.err is a PrintStream.
>   System.err works like System.out
>   except it is normally only used to
>   output error texts. Some programs
>   (like Eclipse) will show the output to
>   System.err in red text, to make it
>   more obvious that it is error text.

From [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/javalang.doc17.html#14132):

```
20.18.3 public static PrintStream err;
```

> The initial value of this variable is
>   a "standard" error output stream,
>   already open and ready to accept
>   output data. Typically, this
>   corresponds to display output or
>   another output destination specified
>   by the host environment or user. By
>   convention, this output stream is used
>   to display error messages or other
>   information that should come to the
>   immediate attention of a user even if
>   the principal output stream, the value
>   of the variable out, has been
>   redirected to a file or other
>   destination that is typically not
>   continuously monitored. Note that this
>   field is not final, so its value may
>   be updated if necessary.

- From Java World [02-qa-1220-console.html](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-12/02-qa-1220-console.html)
- Other post in Stackoverflow [coloring-text-with-java-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139404/coloring-text-with-java-in-windows)

Answer (score 3):

This is a relict from the unix world, where most functionality is available as unix commands which were intended to be chained. The output of one command is used to feed another like here:

```
grep -i 'token' file | mail peter@address.de
```

The pipe symbol only redirects the stdout (System.out), but not the stderr (System.err). So error messages would be seen on the console, and the regular output would go to the mail command.

If there were just one stream, one could not distinguish between them.

Windows, not relying on the command line (This changed in Windows Server 2008!) didn't invent again but just took the unix concepts and made them available in their dos commands, too. It is just that nearly no Windows only users usually know what they are good for.

Answer (score 0):

Both `System.out` and `System.err` always exist in Java.

Depending on your console it *might* be possible to get it to display the two streams in a different colour.

Answer (score 0):

Example use:

```
try {
    Class.doSomething(myFile);
  } catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println("Fatal error performing doSomething: " + e);
    System.exit(-1);
  }
```